# Can't update binded textbox text from another form on c# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a binded textbox control (txtMtrlGrpNum) on form1, i can change text property from the same form:

```
// in frm1

public frm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            Da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from mtrlGrp", cn);
            Da.Fill(Dt);
           
            txtMtrlGrpNum.DataBindings.Add("Text", Dt, "GrpNum");
            matGrpCManager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[Dt];
                  
           }

 public void btn_add1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      
  if (matGrpCManager.Position >= 0)
                {
                   
                    matGrpCManager.AddNew();
                    txtMtrlGrpNum.Text = "123";
                }
         }
```

but when i want to execute button click from another form (Form2) like this:

```
// in frm2

private void btn_add2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {   
         frm1 = new Form1();
         frm1.btn_add1_Click(sender, e);
         frm1.ShowDialog();
{
```

its not changed, its shown empty (""), cause i am using databinding, how to remove binding temporary and re apply it again,... any idea?

Comment: Where is Form1 declared? Maybe you want to post the whole code.

Comment: its declared of course, i modify the question...... to be more clear.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, UWP?  What mode/model are you working against?  And, if changed on the second form, you want it to reflect back on the first form too?

Comment: WinForms, normal data entry form, second form dosnt contain the same control, just i want to excute btn_add1 click event in form1 from form2 by clicking on btn_add2(in form2)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example describing the logic.

In the first form, I created the handler for the button click event. I also added a button to open the second form. When the second form is created, I set the reference to the first form.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // set public // btn_add1_Click
{
    textBox1.Text = "Clicked!";  // set text in text box
}

private void btnOpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();  // create second form
    frm2.frm1 = this;   // set reference to this form
    frm2.Show();  // show second form
}
```

In the second form, add a reference to the first form along with a button to trigger the form1 button handler.

```
public Form1 frm1 = null;  // reference to first form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm1.button1_Click(sender, e);  // call handler in first form
}
```

After the second form is launched, either button will trigger the form1 handler:

[image: Forms Image]

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mike67, but there is misunderstanding in your answer, (Open Form) button should be in Form2 (i want it Compacted with Click Me 2 button), i want to open Form1 and trigger the Form1 (Click Me)button handler when (Click Me 2) button Clicked, i cant change the frm1.textbox text from another form cause its Binded i think!!!